# Loosing connection when updating an identity column on Oracle 12c -

Tags: sql, oracle, identity-column

Oracle 12.1.0.1.0

Here is my SQL (for education purposes):

```
drop table t1 cascade constraints;
table T1 dropped.

create table t1 (n number
generated by default as identity, m number default on null 1);
table T1 created.

insert into t1 values(default, default);
1 rows inserted.

update t1 set m = default;
1 rows updated.

update t1 set n = default;
SQL Error: ORA-00905: No more data to read from socket error
```

So I cannot update a "generated by default as identity" column. Moreover, I lose my connection to the database when I try to do this. Is that a bug / feature or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Not sure about Oracle but Identity column must not be updated and different RDBMS poses restriction on the same.

Comment: @Rahul I didn't understood it myself at first reading, but **the real problem is loosing the connection to the database**. Not being unable to update the identity column.

Comment: I think what has happened is that the server process was actually so astonished (i.e. unprepared) for trying to update an identity that it crashed the connection.

Comment: Check for an ora-600 / similar in the alert log file and any trc files dumped at the same time - definitely sounds like what Simon has said, but the alert log would confirm that

Comment: Better turn trace on, and post the trace output. And, are you using `SQL*Plus` or any GUI tool? If not sqlplus, can you try it again in sqlplus and post the results.

Comment: I tried this code in SQL Developer at first. But it doesn't work in SQL*Plus too. There is no problem in updating an identity GENERATED BY DEFAULT, for example, this code works fine: "update t1 set n = 1;". The problem is in using "default". Never mind, it's just for education. I cannot imagine a situation where I need to update an identity. I just don't understand this behaviour.